# Some files transferred from my iPhone has no read access to other people?

Tags: macos, iphone, file-permissions, pictures

I've just went back from a trip and took lots of pictures with my DSLR and my iPhone. I gave my friend the files, we're both using Mac OS X Snow Leoapard.

Strangely, some files transferred from my iPhone does not have read access to anyone else but me. Does anyone know why this is the case? How can I avoid this in the future?

Furthermore, how do I change the read access to multiple files? This is just for some, not all files from my iPhone. Any terminal commands that I can use?

Comment: "I gave my friend the files..." How?

Comment: Oh ok, through a network with public folders.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you were using different applications to take pictures - possibly the build-in camera app, Little Snapper, instagram, etc. One (or more) of those apparently sets permissions on the images differently than the other apps. Can you determine a pattern as to which photos are right, and which are odd? That should tell you the application. Then, you can either stop using that app, or complain to the developer.

To bulk change permissions from within Terminal, use this:

```
$ cd /path/to/files
$ chmod 644 *
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I actually only use one app to take my pictures, which is the build in camera app. What would you say then? BTW Thanks very much for the terminal command.